# Run two delays at once C++

Tags: c++, delay, turbo-c++

I want to make a program in which there are two dots blinking (with a break of 10ms) simultaneously, but one with delay 200ms and other with delay of 300ms. How can I play these two dots simultaneously from beginning? Is there a better way to that from following:

```
for(int i=1;i<100;i++)
{
  if (i%2==0)
    circle(10,10,2);
  if (i%3==0)
    circle(20,10,2);
  delay(10);
  cleardevice();
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: TurboC++? Are you sure you want to use that ancient compiler?

Comment: Yes, I am a beginner and want to use that only

Comment: Don't use delay there are many ways to time c++.  Try looking at `chrono` and related items.  Wait...that's c++11...I doubt TurboC++ can do that...

Comment: A beginner of what? TurboC++ is not C++.

Comment: @manni66 It's no use to bash Yash Mittal for using Turbo C++. It is most likely the choice of his teacher, which for some reason seems to be *very* common in India, from where I suspect the author is originating from.

Comment: @Jodocus I do not bash Yash Mittal!

Comment: @manni66 "Bash" might be the wrong word indeed, but my statement still holds. This is a precondition the author most likely is unable to circumvent.

Comment: @Jodocus _most likely is unable to avert_ that may be the case. But if he can he should know that he is learning old non standard stuff.

Comment: @YashMittal As a beginner, it is vital that you learn good habits from the very beginning because unlearning is harder than learning. By starting off with a tool that does not support good habits, you will be doing yourself great harm. It's like a carpenter trying to learn how to put in screws whose toolbox contains only hammers.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this instead:

```cpp
int t0=0,t1=0,t=0,s0=0,s1=0,render=1;
for (;;)
 {
 if (some stop condition like keyboard hit ...) break;
 // update time, state 
 if (t>=t0) { render=1; s0=!s0; if (s0) t0+=10; else t0+=200; }
 if (t>=t1) { render=1; s1=!s1; if (s1) t1+=10; else t1+=300; }
 // render
 if (render)
  {
  render=0;
  cleardevice();
  if (s0) circle(10,10,2);
  if (s1) circle(20,10,2);
  }
 // update main time
 delay(10); // Sleep(10) would be better but I am not sure it is present in TC++
 t+=10;
 if (t>10000) // make sure overflow is not an issue
  {
  t -=10000;
  t0-=10000;
  t1-=10000;
  } 
 }
```

Beware the code is untested as I wrote it directly in here (so there might be syntax errors or typos).

The basic idea is having one global time `t` with small enough granularity (`10ms`). And for each object have time of event (`t0,t1`) state of object (`s0,s1`) and periods (`10/200 , 10/300`).

If main time reach the event time swap the state on/off and update event time to next state swap time.

This way you can have any number of objects just make sure your main time step is small enough.

The render flag just ensures that the scene is rendered on change only.

To improve timing you can use **RDTSC** instead of `t+=10` and actually measure how much time has passed with **CPU** frequency accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

To display the two circles simultaneously in the first round, you have to satisfy both conditions `i%2==0` and `i%3==0` at once. You can achieve it by simply changing

```
for(int i=1;i<100;i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
//        ↑ zero here
```